# What is the difference between an IORef and an MVar?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ioref

I'm having a little trouble understanding the basic difference between the IORef type and the MVar type in Haskell. Can someone help me out with this? They appear to solve the same problem. MVar seems to be targeted at multithreading, but IORef has the atomicModifyIORef function.

Thanks!

Comment: MVars represent a queue-like abstraction which can take at most one element with blocking semantics, whereas an IORef has always one element in it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`MVar` is, like you said, targeted at multithreading while `IORef` can be used both as mutable variable in a single threaded program or as a synchronization construct in a multithreaded program.

`IORef` can be used together with `atomicModifyIORef` to get compare-and-swap (CAS) behavior: writers and readers can synchronize on a single pure value, stored in the `IORef`. Readers use `readIORef` to read a value and writers use `atomicModifyIORef` to write a value. Note that `atomicModifyIORef` doesn't let writers perform any side effects inside the critical section (i.e. they can only use a pure function when atomically changing the value).

`MVar` allows you to implement arbitrary critical sections (using `withMVar`), that may contain side effects. They can also be used just like an `IORef` (as described in the previous paragraph), but at a higher cost.

If you want an intuition for what kind of semantic `IORef` implements its the same as the CAS semantics Rich Hickey describes in a talk on Clojure's concurrency model: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey

Edit: In addition, you cannot run into deadlocks using `IORef` (but there still might be contention, causing retries).

Comment: I implemented database connection pool for use in web app. It requires only CAS actions and there's only one object it works with: the list of connections. I am using MVar to hold a Pool. Would you recommend to change it to IORef ? You are saying MVar incurs "a higher cost". Are there any benchmarks ?

Comment: I would use an `IORef`. This is what we use in the GHC I/O manager to store an `IntMap` that maps file descriptors to callbacks. Remember that `IORefs` (and `MVars`) are lazy so you'd have to do something like: `do !_ <- atomicModifyIORef ref (\ m -> let m' = insert k v m in (m', m')` if you want the result to be evaluated in the writer instead of the reader. I don't have any benchmarks handy.

Comment: @tibbe is there any thumb-rule for when one should use an `IORef` and when one should use an `MVar`?